# I cannot open any GUI application after do 'apt-get remove gnome*' - what can I do?

Tags: gnome, gtk

Every time I run UI applications like firefox or chrome or qtoctave etc I get these GTK warning:

```
(firefox:27271): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:27271): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:27271): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:27271): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_long_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:27271): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(firefox:27271): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion `GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed

(firefox:27271): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_icon_theme_prepend_search_path: assertion `GTK_IS_ICON_THEME (icon_theme)' failed

(firefox:27271): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:27271): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

(firefox:27271): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_settings_set_string_property: assertion `GTK_SETTINGS (settings)' failed

** (firefox:27271): WARNING **: Failed to open webapp application path dir /usr/share/gnome-fallback/unity-webapps/userscripts: Error opening directory '/usr/share/gnome-fallback/unity-webapps/userscripts': No such file or directory

** (firefox:27271): WARNING **: Failed to open webapp application path dir /usr/share/gnome/unity-webapps/userscripts: Error opening directory '/usr/share/gnome/unity-webapps/userscripts': No such file or directory

** (firefox:27271): WARNING **: Failed to open webapp application path dir /usr/local/share/unity-webapps/userscripts: Error opening directory '/usr/local/share/unity-webapps/userscripts': No such file or directory

** (firefox:27271): WARNING **: Failed to open webapp application path dir /usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts: Error opening directory '/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts': No such file or directory
```

I am guessing this is because I once accidentally did `sudo apt-get remove gnome*`.
But I don't know how to resolve this.

Can anyone please help me resolve this?

Comment: **Can** you open a program or not? Do you get those messages **only** in the terminal or you get a window?

Comment: Those errors are because of a theme that is no longer working. How did you fix the "sudo apt-get remove gnome*"?

Comment: I would advice to backup all your important files and re-install.

Comment: @user153467 Please, respond to some of our request giving more information about your problem. You can create comments to tell us

Answer (score 0):

These errors are normal, as much as you'd think they are problems with the program, or the GTK. Ignore them.

Comment: So "I  am guessing this is because I once accidentally did sudo apt-get remove gnome*." has nothing to do with it?

Comment: You are correct, your accidental `sudo apt-get remove gnome*` has nothing to do with the sporadic GTK errors. I suspect that nobody debugs them, because they could be spending their time on something more useful, and the application isn't crashing, and it doesn't have any unintended usability consequences.